# function/looping errors

Tags: r

Here's my code and I'm getting the following error:

Error in data[, 1] = rnorm(n, m, sd) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

no idea what I'm doing wrong.
i need to **double loop it** now, basically **i need to vary k to be 2 and 3 and n to be 10 and 15**. i know i need to create a **function**, create a second matrix, add the for *for j in 1:k in the code*... I'm trying to add all that but not sure how to do it.

```
library(fGarch)

#n reps =10
rep=10

#begin function here, need to vary n and k, when k=2 n=10, when k3 n=15
fun=function(n, k, m, sd, sk){

#prepare to store data  
data=matrix(0,nrow=k, ncol=3)
db=matrix(0,nrow=rep, ncol=3)
final=NULL
for (j in 1:rep)
{   
  for (i in 1:k)
  {
#generate data under normal, skewed, and logistic distributions here    
  data[,1]=rnorm(n, m, sd)
  data[,2]=rsnorm(n, m, sd, sk)
  data[,3]=rlogis(n, m, sd) 
}
final[j]=db
}
}
```

Comment: You should explain a bit more, on what you are trying to do and do a little search on the error. I am sure, it has been addressed. `subscript out of bounds` is generally when you are trying to access an array or vector out of its boundary.

Comment: i'm trying to generate data for a meta analysis. 1- generate data following a normal distribution, 2- generate data following a skewed distribution, 3- generate data following a logistic distribution. i need to loop this because the # of studies in each meta will be either 10 or 15. k or total number of studies in the meta will be 5. i need to loop twice to repeat this process 10 times. database should be 3 columns (distributions) by 65 rows x 10 reps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few typos and a parenthesis issue. The following code works:

```
library(fGarch)

rep=10
data=matrix(0,nrow=10*rep, ncol=3)

for (i in 1:rep){
  data[(10*(i-1)+1):(10*i),1]<-rnorm(10, 100, 15)
  data[(10*(i-1)+1):(10*i),2]<-rsnorm(10, 100, 15,1)
  data[(10*(i-1)+1):(10*i),3]<-rlogis(10, 100, 15)
}
```

Notice the additional set of parenthesis in `data[(10*(i-1)+1):(10*i),1]` It is worth noting that a `for` loop here is completely unnecessary, and very un-R-like, i.e. likely to lead to bad habits in R. The same result can be had with:

```
data[,1]<-rnorm(10*rep, 100, 15)
data[,2]<-rsnorm(10*rep, 100, 15, 1)
data[,3]<-rlogis(10*rep, 100, 15)
```

Edit: Updated now. Try it again

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for your suggestion! I'm using the package fGarch for the rsnorm function. I made your edits and still got the following error "Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: Try it again now that I edited it. If you copy and paste my first code block it should work.

Comment: beautiful! it works! thanks a million! if you don't mind helping me a bit more, i need to double loop it now, basically i need to vary k to be 2 and 3 and n to be 10 and 15. i know i need to create a function, create a second matrix, add the for for j in 1:k in the code... I'm trying to add all that. I wish I could show you what I have so far but don't know how to do it through here. i'm going to try to add a comment to see if that works.

Comment: i need to double loop it now, basically i need to vary k to be 2 and 3 and n to be 10 and 15. i know i need to create a function, create a second matrix, add the for for j in 1:k in the code... I'm trying to add all that but not sure how to do it. here's my code so far
library(fGarch)

rep=10
fun=function(n, k)
data=matrix(0,nrow=n*rep, ncol=3)
final=matrix(0,nrow=, ncol=3)

for (j in 1:rep)
{   
  for (i in 1:k)
  {
  data[,1]=rnorm(10*rep, 100, 15)
  data[,2]=rsnorm(10*rep, 100, 15, 1)
  data[,3]=rlogis(10*rep, 100, 15) 
}

Comment: what does k represent?

Comment: k represents # of studies included in a meta analysis, n represents sample size in each study. here's what i have so far: #begin function here, need to vary n and k, when k=2 n=10, when k3 n=15
fun=function(n, k){
  
#prepare to store data  
data=matrix(0,nrow=k, ncol=3)
final=matrix(0,nrow=rep, ncol=3)

for (j in 1:rep)
{   
  for (i in 1:k)
  {
#generate data under normal, skewed, and logistic distributions here    
  data[,1]=rnorm(10*rep, 100, 15)
  data[,2]=rsnorm(10*rep, 100, 15, 1)
  data[,3]=rlogis(10*rep, 100, 15) 
}
final=[j,]=data
}
}

Comment: by the way thanks a million for helping me. i'm eternally grateful. i really struggle with looping in r